# Table row display one by one on Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, loops, jakarta-ee, struts

My jsp code like below

```
<table>
 <logic:iterate name="students" id="nameObj" scope="session">
  <tr>
    <td> <bean:write name="nameObj" property="studentId"/></td>
    <td> <bean:write name="nameObj" property="studentName"/></td>
    <td> <bean:write name="nameObj" property="studentClass"/></td>
    <td> <bean:write name="nameObj" property="mark"/></td>
    <td> <bean:write name="nameObj" property="percentage"/></td>
  </tr>      
 </logic:iterate>
</table>
```

Here I want to show data on jsp after each iterate, Like 1st row after 1st iterate, 2nd row after 2nd iterate and so on.

Can any body suggest any technology in jsp to perform this task.

Comment: Please be clear on what you are asking. The code above would be enough to show the table row by row and written in struts 1.x version. Do you want equivalent for jsp?

Comment: Yes, I understand this code is enough  to show data on JSP. I want to show each row and for each iterate. I don't what to show all row after all iterate done.you get my question?

Comment: In my understanding HTML renders completely and shows the content. You can refer the [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664995/delay-each-iteration-of-loop-by-a-certain-time) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop) for your reference.

Comment: It's not about Jquery or javascript, I need HTML renders only.